# How to convert array into string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I receive data from a table. And save them in array.

I am wondering how to convert array into string with the following format.

In my request,users can add new rows and type in questions and answers.

That's why I think I can put all data in the "form:input"

My code:

```
var param = [];
$("#tblPets tbody tr").each(function(index){

 param.push({
    question: $("textarea.question", this).val(),
    answer: $("textarea.answer", this).val(),
 });

});
var json = JSON.stringify(param); 

    $("form #queAns").val(json);
```

I can convert this array into JSON string.but the format is not what im looking for.

For example:

I hope my string can look like:

Question,Answer|Question,Answer|Question,Answer|

How to do this??

Comment: Why are you making up your own serialization rather than using a standard, well-supported one such as JSON?

Comment: Look at jQuery `Map()`

Comment: Why not directly create a string with the desired format instead of first looping and pushing records into the array?

Comment: Try [Array.prototype.toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2) or [JSON.stringify(array)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3) or even [Array.prototype.join](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5).

Comment: Why is this on hold as off-topic? He has an attempted solution, and he obviously doesn't want to use the standard serialization. I don't see why this is marked as off-topic. @Matt Ball, Please elaborate.

Comment: @AndrewK because the OP did not provide evidence of an effort to solve the problem on their own, as per the stated close details below. As it says: _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."_ The OP has not demonstrated a minimal understanding of the problem being solved; consequently, the question is off topic.

Comment: @Matt Ball, he is asking for help/advice for how to solve this problem that he doesn't know how to solve. He attempted to use JSON.stringify but that did not pan out, and he did not know where to go from there. I disagree, but obviously others agree that this is off-topic so I will concede to that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JQuery's `$.map()` function, and inside that looping over the properties on the object.

```
var param = [];
$("#tblPets tbody tr").each(function(index){

 param.push({
    question: $("textarea.question", this).val(),
    answer: $("textarea.answer", this).val(),
 });

});

console.log(param);

var result = '';
$.map(param, function(n) {
    for(var prop in n){
        result += n[prop] + ',';
    }
    result = result.substring(0, result.length-1) + '|';
});

console.log(result);
```

[jsFiddle - updated to remove extra comma](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3QBz/1/)

[StackOverflow re: iterating over object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: Thanks!! I use your code and it works good.I got what I want.but there  is a little issue. The Result looks  like:Question,Answer,|Question,Answer,|  I dont wanna have "," after answer. So how to do it?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I've updated the code and the jsFiddle to remove that extra space.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many method exist to convert array into string:

You can use `.tostring()`:

```
myArray .toString();
```

Try this:

Javascript:

```
function myFunction()
{
  var myArray = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  myArray .toString();
  var x=document.getElementById("demo");
  x.innerHTML=myArray;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to convert the array into a String.</p>
```

[Live Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tostring_array)

Comment: is there a way in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, but here is an idea of how it would look like if you want the exact encoding and are ok with looping over the array.

```
var param = [], string = '';
$("#tblPets tbody tr").each(function(index){

 param.push({
    question: $("textarea.question", this).val(),
    answer: $("textarea.answer", this).val(),
 });

});

param.forEach( function (obj) { 
string += obj.question+','obj.answer+'|';
})
```